# $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{1000000}\binom{2000000}{2n}\cdot{p}^{2n}\cdot(1-p)^{2000000-2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{1000000}\binom{2000000}{2n}\cdot{p}^{2n}\cdot(1-p)^{2000000-2n}$

How can I go about finding the above sum?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\sum_{n=0}^{[r/2]}\binom r{2n}a^{2n}b^{r-2n}=(a+b)^r+(a-b)^r$$

Comment: Could you show me how you derived the RHS from the LHS? I've already managed to do it in reverse but have no clue how I'd go about doing it the other way. Also does this identity have a name?

Comment: @MathWolf, Observe that we need to retain every even term . If we have to retain every third term, we need to add $$(a-b)^r+(a-bw)^r+(a-bw^2)^r$$ where $w$ is a complex cube root of unity.