# Finding the sum of a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

May I ask how do I find the sum of the following series:

$$ 1 + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^6}{6!}...$$ Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? In what course did this question arise? [Context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is important in writing a helpful answer.

Comment: Think about  $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, the cube root of unity and the power series for exponential function.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046373/sum-limits-n-01000000-binom20000002n-cdotp2n-cdot1-p2000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try computing the power series for
$$
e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2x}+e^x
$$
where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Try to write this function without complex numbers.

Comment: I see, I've gotten rid of the complex numbers by making use of the roots of unity (1+w+w^2=0).  Dividing this expression by 3 gives the series I want. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed! Good work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: Suppose you have a power series
$$F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k.$$
If $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, then we have
$$1 + \zeta^m + \zeta^{2m} + \cdots + \zeta^{(k - 1)m} =
\begin{cases}
0 &\textrm{if $n \mid m$} \\
n & \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Therefore
$$F(x) + F(\zeta x) + \cdots + F(\zeta^{n - 1}x) = n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{nk}x^{nk}.$$
You can generalize this to isolate the coefficients of a power series on any desired arithmetic progression.